# How to calculate wifi dynamic frequency selection probability

Tags: wifi

I have no idea how I can handle this question.

Let's say 802.11h AP points are spread out throughout a street.

```
#52, #56 ...., #140
```

A bus that is connected to #52 channel is travelling along that street with a constant speed.

What's probability that that bus will have to change its AP?

Thanks.

Comment: you should rephrase the question. Give details!!!. it is no clear. To me, sounds like the only and quick answer is 100% of probablity, as you do not specify travel time, distance, metrics, etc. the bus at a given time will be out of AP range. But anyway your question sounds like a algorithm question, which qualifies it as "not belongs here"

Comment: @Luis: Since when were algorithmic questions off-topic here?  Even the [Help Center/On Topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) article lists "Software Algorithms" as the second bullet.

Answer (score 4):

This almost sounds like a trick question.
The way it's written the answer is certainly **100%**.
That is, unless the bus's constant speed is 0 or the AP's range is ∞.